# How to fetch data from Cursor Oracle/Toad

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, toad

I have function that returns cursor with multiple date values and i need to fetch those data one by one into this:

```
CALLMISUSER01.INSERT_DEP004(First data of the cursor, Second data of the cursor, Third data of the cursor. . . etc);
```

my main function is:

```
Create or replace FUNCTION Rep_dates(pdt_ref_date IN DATE)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
    pcr_result SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN pcr_result FOR
    SELECT  
        trunc(pdt_ref_date),
        trunc(pdt_ref_date) - 1,
        trunc(pdt_ref_date) - 2,
        trunc(pdt_ref_date) - 3,
        trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'mm'),       
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'MM'), -1) first_day_of_last_month,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'MM'), -2) first_day_of_last_month,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'MM'), -3) first_day_of_last_month,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'Q'), -6) first_day_of_last_quarter,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'Q'), -9) first_day_of_last_quarter,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'Q'), -12) first_day_of_last_quarter,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'Q'), -15) first_day_of_last_quarter,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'Q'), -18) first_day_of_last_quarter
    FROM dual;

    RETURN pcr_result;
END;
```

Comment: Are your procedure and function being created inside a package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, give proper aliases for the columns returned as `REF CURSOR` from your function. Then you may define a matching `RECORD` type and `FETCH` the cursor into it. This is one method you may refer to individual columns. Other option is to define separate variables for each column.

**Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rep_dates(pdt_ref_date IN DATE)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
    pcr_result SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN pcr_result FOR
    SELECT  
        trunc(pdt_ref_date) as  pdt_ref_date,
        trunc(pdt_ref_date) - 1 pdt_ref_date_1,
        trunc(pdt_ref_date) - 2 pdt_ref_date_2,
        trunc(pdt_ref_date) - 3 pdt_ref_date_3,
        trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'mm') as pdt_ref_date_mon ,       
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'MM'), -1) first_day_of_last_month,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'MM'), -2) first_day_of_2nd_last_month,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'MM'), -3) first_day_of_3rd_last_month,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'Q'), -6) first_day_of_last_quarter_1,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'Q'), -9) first_day_of_last_quarter_2,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'Q'), -12) first_day_of_last_quarter_3,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'Q'), -15) first_day_of_last_quarter_4,
        add_months(trunc(pdt_ref_date, 'Q'), -18) first_day_of_last_quarter_5
    FROM dual;

    RETURN pcr_result;
END;
/
```

**Calling block**

```
DECLARE
     m_curs                        SYS_REFCURSOR;
     TYPE pcr_rec IS RECORD ( 
     pdt_ref_date                  DATE,
     pdt_ref_date_1                DATE,
     pdt_ref_date_2                DATE,
     pdt_ref_date_3                DATE,
     pdt_ref_date_mon              DATE,
     first_day_of_last_month       DATE,
     first_day_of_2nd_last_month   DATE,
     first_day_of_3rd_last_month   DATE,
     first_day_of_last_quarter_1   DATE,
     first_day_of_last_quarter_2   DATE,
     first_day_of_last_quarter_3   DATE,
     first_day_of_last_quarter_4   DATE,
     first_day_of_last_quarter_5   DATE
 );
 pcr_res pcr_rec;
BEGIN
     m_curs := rep_dates(SYSDATE);--pass your pdt_ref_date
     FETCH m_curs INTO pcr_res;

     CALLMISUSER01.INSERT_DEP004(pcr_res.pdt_ref_date,pcr_res.pdt_ref_date_1,
      --..... --all other column aliases.
      pcr_res.first_day_of_last_quarter_5);

END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. @Kaushik Nayak